# Converting a signed char to an int in c

Tags: c

Im having an issue converting a signed string into an int.

```
char *crn1, *crn2, *credit1, credit2;
char course1, course2;

crn1=strtok(course1,"/");
credit1=strtok(NULL,"/");

crn2 = strtok(course2,"/");
credit2 = strtok(NULL,"/");
```

Im trying to convert the signed char credit1 or credit2 to an integer for math used later on in my code. I either get a huge number or an error.

Comment: `strtok` accepts a `char*` as its first parameter but you're passing in an unassigned `char` value. Your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `atoi` should work

Comment: can you help me convert this to an atoi example?

Comment: Strings are neither signed nor unsigned, and a string containing a text representation of an integer, regardless of signedness, is not a `char`.

Comment: @rando, Post needs more context.  Suggest posting how `credit1` get assigned its  _signed string_.

Comment: *"signed char credit1 or credit2"* -- `credit1` and `credit2` are *pointers to char* not `char` -- did you mean `course1` and `course2`??

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) (which is the safer version of [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *str = "5";
  int n;
  n = strtol(str, NULL, 10);
  printf("n+1 is %d\n", n+1);
}
```

Using `atoi`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *str = "1";
  int n;
  n = atoi(str);
  printf("n+1 is %d\n", n+1);
}
```

If instead of converting the digits in the string into an integer, you'd rather use the numerical value of the character, you can:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c = 'a';
    printf("ascii code of %c is %hhu\n", c, c);
    printf("after %c is %c with ascii code %u", c, c+1, c+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend `strtol()`, you need to get it right.  It's declared as [`long int strtol( const char *restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4).  Your current posted usage ignores the converted value of the string, tries to use an `int *` where a `char **` should be and not only will print out the wrong result, it might fail badly as it's undefined behavior.

Comment: You're totally right. Momentary brain damage :-P sorry!

Comment: We've all been there... :-)

Comment: What are you declaring with the argument `n=long int strtol(str,NULL,10);`

Comment: Long story short, it will parse the string `str` as a base-`10` integer and return its value (which is then stored in `n`).